# How to express “getting caught up on” in german

Tags: word-usage, english-to-german, german-to-english, phrase-request

I was wondering if somebody could help me with the following translation:

> “I didn’t expect him to like the entire plan. But the first step was the first thing **he got caught up on**.”

That is, “get caught up on” in the sense of have problems with/have serious questions about, etc. Is there a similar phrase in German? I tried some searches with “hängen bleiben”, but not sure if this is 100% correct.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, AmEn here, but when used that way is it not more common to say "got hung up on"? "Get caught up on" to me almost always means he learned something quickly, or otherwise was behind but is now up to speed

Comment: Yes, that is likely the better saying. I am also American, and this phrase for some reason was the one that came to my mind. Yours is admittedly more precise.

Comment: During my time in Heidelberg the literal translation of Bruce Wayne’s suggestion was heard quite often among astrophysicists: „sich daran aufhängen“. But it certainly isn’t good German and I cannot tell how common it is outside this community, which, anyway, is incredibly prone to use anglicisms!

Answer (score 3):

An expression that would fit would be

> an etwas Anstoß nehmen

which would be used when the thing faced opposition by the subject

more neutral would be

> das erste, woran er sich aufgehalten hat, war ...

wich would be closer to your "hängenbleiben", but much more common.

If you want to be more colloquial, you can use expressions like

> das erste, über was er gestolpert ist, war ...

another colloquial expression would be

> das erste, was ihm aber sauer aufgestoßen ist, war ...

(figuratively, a sour burp)

Answer (score 2):

Other possibilities:

> - das Erste, was er bemängelte
> - das Erste, was er beanstandete
> - das Erste, was ihm missfiel
> - das Erste, was ihm gegen den Strich ging
> - das Erste, was ihm nicht passte

Answer (score 2):

A literal translation would be

> Schon an der ersten Sache hat er sich verfangen

A more common but colloquial way would be to say

> Schon am ersten Schritt hat er sich völlig verheddert (*to get entangled*)

Comment: Gelungene Übersetzung, finde ich. Aber: "am" oder "beim"? Und "völlig" ist vielleicht eine unnötige Verstärkung.

Comment: @EarlDumarest: stimmt, mit *am* und *beim* habe ich auch lange gehadert, ich denke es geht beides (an einer Sache sein, bei einer Sache sein). Das *völlig* entspricht dem Unterschied *caught* und *caught **up*** etwas mehr, aber nur marginal, man könnte es durchaus auch weglassen (verheddert wird aber von den Leuten oft verstärkt *völlig/total/ganz/komplett/...*)

Comment: Mein Hintergedanke war, dass ohne "völlig" ist die Übersetzung eher wertungsneutral und nicht mehr "colloquial". Aber mein Englisch ist nicht gut genug für so was.

Comment: @Takkat sehr interessant. Kann man "sich verheddern" auch im Sinne von: Ich habe den Text gelesen, aber habe mich an einem bestimmten Punkt verheddert, und kam nicht weiter. (= I got caught up on a specific point/was confused, so I couldn't continue)?

Comment: @Mark: das kann man schon sagen, *verheddert* ist nicht sehr spezifisch, aber dafür endgültig ;)

Comment: @Mark Verheddern bedeutet nicht zwangsläufig auch Bewegungsunfähigkeit. Ein Fisch kann sich in einem Netz verheddern. Er kommt dann nicht mehr frei, springt aber trotzdem noch vergeblich wild umher. Übertragen auf das Lesen: Der Leser erreicht eine Stelle, hat das Verständnis verloren und beginnt im Text vor und zurück zu springen. Ohne Erfolg, das Verständnis will sich nicht wieder einstellen. - Nein, "sich verheddern" ist einfach ein schönes Verb.

Comment: @Takkat  Thanks! Letzte Frage:) "Ich habe mich mitten im Satz verheddert" = I got caught up/tripped over my words in the middle of my sentence.? Oder muss man sich an/in ETWAS verheddern?

Comment: @Mark: das geht auch... :)

Comment: @Takkat Sometimes I hate this language....sometimes I love it :)